# Please help me to prove that $|f(x)| \le M \Vert x\Vert$ around $0$ when $|f(x)| \le \Vert x \Vert^\alpha$ around $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

**Question:**

Suppose that $0<r<1$ and that $f\colon B_1(0) \to \Bbb R$ is continuously differentiable.

If there is an $\alpha>0$ such that $|f(x)| \le \Vert x \Vert^{\alpha}$ for all $x\in B_r(0)$, then prove that there is an $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M\Vert x \Vert$ for $x\in B_r(0)$

---

**Solution trial:** let $x_k\in B_r(0)$ be a sequence with $x_k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, $f$ is continouos as well.

Since $f$ is continouos and $x_k\to 0$, it must be that $f(x_k)\to f(0)$.

That is, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}|f(x_k)|\le \lim_{k\to\infty}\Vert x_k \Vert^{\alpha}=0.$$

---

This is just an idea that may not work. Please help me find a valid proof. Thank you.

Comment: What is $r{}{}{}$?

Comment: The fact that $\lim x_n\leq \lim y_n$ does not in any way imply $x_n\leq y_n$. So, this approach will not work.  Think about this: your argument works just as well if $\lvert f(x_k)\rvert$ and $\|x_k\|^{\alpha}$ trade places!

Comment: That's to say, I am not in a right way to solve this. Well, can you solve the question properly? @nrpeterson

Comment: $r$ is any number btw 0 and 1. @ChrisEagle

Comment: Given in the book, $0<r<1$. That's $r\in (0,1)$ i guess. @nrpeterson

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: $B_1(0)$ is the domain of $f$ @jouge

Comment: @B11b, where is $B_1(0)$? in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I guess $B_1(0)$ in $\Bbb R$. There is no another choice. it is not given in the question:( @jougle.

Comment: No no. I asked the question 11.5.7.(that's I underlined the question with green pencil) Not 11.5.8. $\Bbb R^n$ you saw is in the question 11.5.8. @jouge

Comment: @jouge Will you help me??

Comment: FYI, the $\Vert$ symbol is produced by `\Vert`. I forgot to fix that in the title.

Comment: Thank you. I dont know this symbol. Please help me to solve this question if you mind:) @dfeuer

Comment: By the way, how to write $lim_{k\to \infty}$ properly? @dfeuer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma:** There exist $\delta > 0$ and $M>0$ such that whenever $\Vert x \Vert < \delta$, $|f(x)| \le M \Vert x \Vert$.

Warning: I have not mucked about with this sort of mathematics in a number of years, so please check my argument carefully.

Since $f$ has continuous first partial derivatives at $0$, it is differentiable at $0$.

That is,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {f(x) - f(0) - x \cdot \nabla f(0)}{\Vert x \Vert} = 0.$$

Since $|f(0)| \le \Vert 0 \Vert^\alpha = 0$, $f(0)=0$.

Thus $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {f(x) - x \cdot \nabla f(0)}{\Vert x \Vert} = 0.$$

That is, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $\Vert x \Vert < \delta$, $$\left\vert  \frac {f(x) - x \cdot \nabla f(0)}{\Vert x \Vert} \right\vert < \epsilon.$$

Rearranging the fraction,
$$\left\vert \frac {f(x)}{\Vert x \Vert} - \frac {x \cdot \nabla f(0)}{\Vert x \Vert} \right\vert < \epsilon.$$

Now the quantity $$q(x) := \frac{x\cdot\nabla f(0)}{\Vert x \Vert}$$ does not depend on the magnitude of $x$, so by a continuity and compactness argument, it is bounded.

Thus the quantity $$\frac {f(x)}{\Vert x \Vert}$$ is also bounded.
$\square$

Comment: Sorry I am confused too much:(

Comment: But in the question, Both $B_1(0)$ and $B_r(0)$ are used. There is a thing, i guess

Comment: You would be explanatory things. But I dont understand what i need to solve this question.

Answer (score 2):

The following argument/discussion makes no assumption about the dimension of the domain of
$f(x)$; that is, we take all balls $B_s(0) \subset R^N$ for some positive integer $N$.

That being said, I break this problem into three different cases:

First, consider the situation $\alpha = 1$; then we have $|f(x)| \le ||x||$, and choosing $M= 1$, we are done.

The second case I will consider is $\alpha > 1$;  here we may write $|f(x) | \le ||x||^{\alpha} = |x||^{\alpha - 1}||x||$, and since $||x||^{\alpha - 1} < r^{\alpha - 1}$ for $x \in B_r(0)$, we can set $M = \rho^{\alpha - 1}$ for any $\rho \ge r$ and we are done.

**NOTA BENE:**  It should be observed that here I am taking $B_r(0)$ to be the *open* ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$, that is, $B_r(0) = \{x : ||x|| < r\}$.

The remaining, and of course the most difficult case, is $0 < \alpha < 1$; here we may still affirm that $||x||^\alpha = ||x||^{\alpha  -1}||x||$, but only for $||x|| > 0$; since $\alpha - 1 < 0$,

$||x||^{\alpha -1} = \frac{1}{||x||^{1 - \alpha}}$

is in fact undefined for $x= 0$, and becomes arbitrarily large as $x \to 0$; therefore it can't serve as the starting point to derive the kind if estimate we need.  These difficulties may be circumvented, however, by  exploiting the fact that $f(x)$ is differentiable in the vicinity of $0$.  Let's do it like this:  pick $r'$ such that $0 < r' < r$, and consider the open annular region $A(r', r) = B_r(0) - \bar{B}_{r'}(0)$, where $\bar{B}_{r'}(0)$ denotes the closure of $B_{r'}(0)$;  $A(r', r)$ looks like the orthogonal projection of a donut (or "torus" for the mathematically inclined ;) ) into a plane in the two dimensional case.  Now for $x \in A(r', r)$ we may legitimately assert that

$|f(x)| \le ||x||^\alpha = ||x||^{\alpha -1}||x|| = \frac{1}{||x||^{1 - \alpha}}||x|| < \frac{1}{(r')^{1 - \alpha}}||x||$

since $||x|| > r'$ , hence $||x||^{1 - \alpha} > (r')^{1 - \alpha}$for such $x$.  So we can take

$M' = \frac{1}{(r')^{1 - \alpha}}$,

*on $A(r', r)$*, and we obtain $|f(x)| \le M'||x||$, again *on $A(r', r)$*  But it remains to deal with $x \in \bar{B}_{r'}(0)$; this is where the derivative of $f(x)$ enters the picture.  For $x \in \bar{B}_{r'}(0)$, consider the ray
$tx$ where $0 \le t \le 1$; we compute $\frac{df(xt)}{dt}$ along this path; we have, by the chain rule,

$\frac{df(xt)}{dt} = \nabla f(xt) \cdot \frac{d(xt)}{dt} = \nabla f(xt) \cdot x$;

furthermore,

$f(x) = f(x) - f(0) = \int_0^1 \frac{df(xt)}{dt}dt =  \int_0^1 (\nabla f(xt) \cdot x)dt$,

and since by hypothesis $f(0) = 0$ (by virtue of the assumption that $|f(x)| \le ||x||^\alpha$, as dfeuer pointed out in his answer), we may write

$f(x) = \int_0^1 (\nabla f(xt) \cdot x)dt$,

whence

$|f(x)| = |\int_0^1 (\nabla f(xt) \cdot x)dt| \le \int_0^1 |(\nabla f(xt) \cdot x)|dt$

$\le \int_0^1 (||(\nabla f(xt)|| \: ||x||)dt = ||x||\int_0^1 (||\nabla f(xt))||dt$,

this last equality holding since $||x||$ is constant with respect to $t$.  We now invoke the hypothesis that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $B_1(0)$, hence on $\bar B_{r'}(0) \subset B_1(0)$; thus $\nabla f(x)$ is continuous on $\bar B_{r'}(0)$, and thus (finally!) $||\nabla f(x)||$ is continuous on $\bar B_{r'}(0)$; thus, since $\bar B_{r'}(0)$ is compact, $||\nabla f(x)||$ is bounded on $\bar B_{r'}(0)$ (it actually obtains both its maximum and minimum values over $\bar B_{r'}(0)$ at points *in* $\bar B_{r'}(0)$), thus for some positive real $K$,

$||\nabla f(x)|| < K$

on $\bar B_{r'}(0)$.  Using this fact in the last inequality yields

$|f(x)| \le ||x||\int_0^1 (||\nabla f(xt))||dt \le ||x|| \int_0^1 Kdt = K ||x||$,

holding on $\bar B_{r'}(0)$.  We thus have $|f(x)| \le K ||x||$ holding on $\bar B_{r'}(0)$, and  $|f(x)| \le M' ||x||$ holding on $A(r', r)$; setting $M = \max \{K, M'\}$ we finally arrive at $|f(x)| \le M ||x||$, valid on $B_r(0) = \bar B_{r'}(0) \cup A(r', r)$.  And we are done, and this time I mean, "DONE!"

Whew!  Lots of details in that one!

The problem being resolved, a few (hopefully germane) comments may be made:

In looking at the derivations given in the answers, one might ask just why bother with the arguments based directly on $||x||^\alpha$, when the differentiability argument
used both by dfeuer and myself, though in slightly different forms, seems like it might be capable of resolving the question.  One reason is that $f(x)$, though differentiable on 
$B_1(0)$, may in fact *not* be differentiable on $\bar B_1(0)$; for instance, $||\nabla f||$ may become unbounded as $||x|| \to 1$.  An example of such an $f(x)$ is provided by the function $y(x) = 1 - \sqrt{(1 - x^2)}$ (which describes the "bottom half" of the circle
$x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 1)$, defined on the open interval $(-1, 1) \subset R$; $y(x)$ can in fact be *defined* on the closed interval $[-1, 1]$, but $y'(x)$ only exists on its interior, $(-1, 1)$.  Since the derivative $y'(x)$ becomes arbitrarily large on $(-1, 1)$,
an estimate based on a simple bound of the derivative fails in a case such as this

And I see no reason, off the top of my head, why we can't allow $r = 1$!